# Check If N and Its Double Exist

Tags: c++, arrays, search

This is from one of the problems in the tutorials at leetcode, it asks:

Given an array arr of integers, check if there exists two integers N and M such that N is the double of M ( i.e. N = 2 * M).

Here's my attempted solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool checkIfExist(vector<int>& arr) {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if (arr[i] == 2*arr[j]){
                return true;}
        }
    }
}
};
```

I end up getting the error:

```
Line 10: Char 1: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 error generated.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
I fixed the bug by adding the return false statement as suggested, and also fixed the loop on j to run till arr.size(). However leetcode still won't accept my solution. It passes the compile test, but not the submission:
[image: error]

What's up with that now? Is it not recognizing the negative values in the array? Sorry if these are very silly questions, I'm rather new to programming in general, feel like I should've mentioned this.

Comment: You need a `return false;` before your functions closing brace.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I also realized I should've let the loop on j to run till arr.size(), silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use a [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) for solving this problem:

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>


static const struct Solution {
    using ValueType = std::uint_fast16_t;
    static bool checkIfExist(
        const std::vector<int>& arr
    ) {
        std::unordered_map<ValueType, ValueType> num_counts;

        for (const auto& num : arr) {
            ++num_counts[num];
        }

        for (const auto& num : arr) {
            if (
                (num && num_counts.find(num * 2) != std::end(num_counts)) ||
                (!num && num_counts[num] > 1)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

---

#### Code

```
struct Solution {
    static bool checkIfExist(
        const std::vector<int>& arr
    ) {
        std::unordered_map<int, int> num_counts;

        for (const auto& num : arr) {
            ++num_counts[num];
        }

        for (const auto& num : arr) {
            if (
                (num && num_counts.find(num * 2) != std::end(num_counts)) ||
                (!num && num_counts[num] > 1)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I saw a few solutions implementing this method. It is not something I have studied myself though, hopefully I'll get to it one day. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If there are n numbers, you would loop n² times, say for n == 1_000, 1_000_000 times.

Better is you keep a set of doubled numbers (mind 2*k can also be written as k<<1).
And a set of half numbers when the number is even (k/2, k>>1). *This can be the same set, `complementary_numbers`.*

Then if you encounter a number that is in "either" set you have found a solution. This needs only n steps and adding to a set is at most log n, so complexity O(n.log n) instead of O(n²): in the order of 100 times faster.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm aware of this complexity issue. I'm a bit new to programming in general so just tried solving it with the simplest algorithm that came to my mind.